# Impact of Padding on the Similarity of two vectors

Tags: machine-learning, similarity

Say I have two document vectors, X1 and X2. Now I padded these with zero vectors to have the maximum document length contraint. Will it impact the similrity between two vectors? Or in general how is it helping us?

Answer (score 2):

I can answer the first part.  It will not affect the similarity between the vectors.  Usually, in document handling, one will use the cosine distance between vectors.  By adding zeros, the cosine distance will not be changed.  You are increasing the dimensionality by adding zeros.  For exmaple, in a two dimensional space [1, 2] and [3, 4] are two points.  in a three dimensions, the same points are represented as [1, 2, 0] and [3, 4, 0].  Even though the dimension is increased the points remain the same.

Comment: This works if you are not working with whole vector space. If it is used model to calculate embeddings it is filling whole vector space, so padding in this case really matters. What happened to me was, that short string converted to embeddings had the cosine similarity smallest with shorter text rather than the most relevant context.